# Ask for password when starting dconf

Tags: dconf

I'd like to have a password request whenever someone tries to start the dconf Editor. Is there any possilility to achieve this?

Comment: BTW, why you want to do this?

Comment: To prevent others from messing around easily when I'm logged in... but I found out it's quite useless...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First edit `/usr/share/applications/dconf-editor.desktop` file as follow:

- From [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) open `dconf-editor.desktop` file using the following command:

  ```
  sudo -i gedit /usr/share/applications/dconf-editor.desktop
  ```
- Find the following line:

  ```
  Exec=dconf-editor
  ```

  and replace it with:

  ```
  Exec=pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY dconf-editor
  ```
- Save the file and close it.

Second, change the permission of `/usr/bin/dconf-editor` file to be executable only by the root. To do this, from terminal run the following command:

```
sudo chmod go-x /usr/bin/dconf-editor
```

Comment: Using dconf editor as root won't work, because it edits the dconf settings of the user it's beeing runned by.

Comment: @the_Seppi It will work like a charm. Just try it. Would you like to make a screen cast to show you?

Comment: Now dconf editor isn't starting at all. How can i undo `chmod go-x`?

Comment: @the_Seppi You probably did something wrong.

Comment: I copy-pasted every command/line-to-be-written. What can I do wrong?

Comment: @the_Seppi So, now, if you run `gksu dconf-editor` from terminal, `dconf-editor` will not start?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to patch the code to make it show a password dialogue. Or to write a wrapper and place it in, say, `/usr/local/bin/dconf-editor`. But all that is security theatre only unless you manage `~/.config/dconf/` differently. By default, it is owned by the user who can thus modify it as she likes.

If you want to prevent certain changes in the configuration to be made, you might want to have a look at Pessulus (https://wiki.gnome.org/Pessulus). But you would have to put in a lot of work as it has been deprecated long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

You should just remove the dconf editor package:

```
sudo apt-get remove dconf-editor
```

so anyone that wants to modify your dconf should know:

1. Your sudo password or
2. How to use dconf command line

There's another option, but should not be used if you don't know what you are doing, which is literally put your `~/.conf/dconf` directory as read-only.